# How to return the name of a variable evaluated in a condition

Tags: php

I want to find out the name of the first variable that has false value while checked in a condition. For example:

```
if (!$value1 || !$value2 || !$value3){

    // return the name of the first false variable - but how?
}
```

PHP evaluates the conditions in brackets and if one of the variables is false then we execute the code. The trick is how to make PHP to tell me which variable is false without examining them manually one by one again. Any ideas?

So far I have one idea, but it's very inefficient.

```
function checkFalseVars($vars){

    foreach($vars as $var){

        $v = $GLOBALS[$var];
        if (!$v){
            return $var;
       }    
    }
    return false;
}  

$value1 = true;
$value2 = false;
$value3 = false;

$vars = array('value1','value2','value3');


if (!$value1 || !$value2 ||!$value3){

    return  checkFalseVars($vars);
    // returns 'value2'
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us what exactly you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: @dustytrash - sometimes I have checks in a functions that terminate it if one the variables passed is empty, null or false. I wonder if it's possible to check them together and somehow know which is the first 'falsely' variable. Would make debugging and error detection a bit easier. But it's more a theory thing. Overall, I wonder if such thing is possible in PHP.

Comment: You're just checking if a variable is false. Of course it's possible

Comment: I think I'm actually asking for something that might not exist in PHP as a built-in function. It's not about determining if something is false or not - that's the easy part. It's about returning the name of the variable which PHP evaluated as false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're averse to your current implementation due to the repeated iteration over the variables (in the `if` statement, and in your `checkFalseVars` function). Your implementation is correct in that if you want to find out which variable is false, you will need to iterate over them, and there's no way around that.

So at this point, you need to take a step back and assess your code, since you don't want to be repeating anything. Since you have to loop over the variables anyway, you may as well have your `if` statement look at the result of that loop, rather than have the `if` statement assessing each variable itself. Since your `checkFalseVars` function returns a false value if none of the variables are false, then you can simply have your `if` statement check the output of that function.

Here is a minor refactoring of your code - I've kept your `checkFalseVars` function as-is. This has the added benefit of keeping the variable checking in a single function, so that if you add more variables to check, you only have to add them to the array that you're passing to the function...You don't need to worry about keeping the variable checking in the `if` statement up to date as well.

```
function checkFalseVars($vars){

    foreach($vars as $var){

        $v = $GLOBALS[$var];
        if (!$v){
            return $var;
       }    
    }
    return false;
}  

$value1 = true;
$value2 = false;
$value3 = false;

$vars = array('value1','value2','value3');


/*
// This was the old technique
if (!$value1 || !$value2 ||!$value3){

    return  checkFalseVars($vars);
    // returns 'value2'
}
*/

// This is the new technique:
$falseVar = checkFalseVars($vars);
if ($falseVar !== false) {
    return $falseVar
}
```

**Edit:** In one of your comments you mention:

> I want get from PHP the information it already knows - which variable was evaluated as false and caused the condition to be triggered.

I want to clarify that PHP does not hold onto information about which comparisons in the `if` evaluated to true or false. Even though PHP's `if` statements are doing evaluations to determine if the `if` statement evaluates to true or false, it doesn't store the results of those evaluations in memory for later use in your code.

Aside from the potential for massive memory consumption if PHP held onto that information, it could also be difficult to work with. An `if` statement can evaluate much more than just a simple `is this variable true or false`, and there can be a whole lot of different expression to evaluate.

Comment: Thank you for a very good explanation of the problem. In the end I did ask for something that didn't exist. And yes, I was hoping to avoid looping through variables after the 'if' check. Also, I wanted to avoid the pain of creating the array with variables names.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to iterate through your values using a simple FOR loop.

```
$values = array($value1, $value2, $value3);
for($i = 0; $i < count($values); $i++){
if($values[$i] == false){echo "Value number $i is false.";}
}
```

This will give you a developer friendly code readout (as in by array which starts at 0.) If you would prefer a more readout which is the same name as your values e.g. $value1, $value2, $value3 - you can make the small change to:

```
$values = array($value1, $value2, $value3);
for($i = 0; $i < count($values); $i++){
if($values[$i] == false){echo "Value number " . ($i + 1) . "is false.";}
}
```

I have provided a working ideone example, here:
https://ideone.com/cdiatK

Comment: Thank you, that's quite useful, but that's not what I'm after. Your solution involves looping through list of values. In my example these values were already checked for PHP for false/true and I don't want to loop through them again to perform the same check. I want get from PHP the information it already knows - which variable was evaluated as false and caused the condition to be triggered.

Comment: @Revover Surely then you can remove your original function, and replace it with mine, placing your code in there to do what you will, as required. If you need it to STOP when it reaches false, simply insert a"break;"

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked for the variable name...

```
function varName( $v ) {
    $trace = debug_backtrace();
    $vLine = file( __FILE__ );
    $fLine = $vLine[ $trace[0]['line'] - 1 ];
    preg_match( "#\\$(\w+)#", $fLine, $match );
    print_r( $match );
}

$value1 = true;
$value2 = true;
$value3 = false;

$values = array($value1, $value2, $value3);
for($i = 0; $i < count($values); $i++)
{

    if($values[$i] == false)
    {
        varName($values[$i]);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. While it's not exactly what I'm after, it did show me show to get the variable name.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @dustytrash and @rtoyo suggestions  I suggested that  you could adapt your code this way:

```
function checkfalseVar(){
    //Use debug_trace() to find the line number that called this function
    $trace = debug_backtrace();
    //Get the contents of the current file.
    $vLine = file( __FILE__ );
    //Get the text of the line of code that called the function
    $fLine = $vLine[ $trace[0]['line'] - 1 ];
    //Use a regular expression to get the list of variable names that were passed as arguments
    preg_match_all( "#\\$(\w+)#", substr($fLine,stripos($fLine,'checkfalseVar')), $match );

    //Loop through each variable name in the argument, to see if that particular argument is null
    foreach($match[1] as $k=>$v){
        // Evaluate if the value of the argument is false; if it is, then return the name.
        if(!func_get_arg($k)) return $v;
    }
    return false;
}

$data=7;
$data2=false;
$data3='';

if(false!==($false=checkfalseVar($data,$data2,$data3))){
      print($false);//output data2;
}
```

however it may not work in every situations (see why in the comments below).

After further thoughts I found another implementation which is a little more complex and not less consuming but have really more advantages than the first version

```
function checkfalseVar2(){
    //define a static variable to track function calls in order to allow  search on same line
        static $counter=0;
     //Use debug_trace() to find the line number that called this function
    $trace = debug_backtrace();
    //Get the contents of the current file.
    $vContent = file_get_contents(__FILE__);
    //get all newlines occurrences in order to allow multiple lines search
    preg_match_all('#\n#',$vContent,$newlines,PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
    $i=0;
    $newlineE=$newlines?$newlines[0][$trace[0]['line']+1][1]:0;  
    //found all matches which fit the $trace variable characteristics
    do{
        $newlineS=$newlines?$newlines[0][$trace[0]['line'] - $i][1]:0;
        $sub=substr($vContent,$newlineS,$newlineE-$newlineS);
        preg_match_all('#checkfalseVar2#i',$sub,$match,PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
        $i++;
    }while(!$match[0]);
    isset($match[0][$counter])?$occurrence=$match[0][$counter][1]+$newlineS:$occurrence=$match[0][0][1]+$newlineS;
    //get the list of the functions args as a string
    $signature='';
    $r=$l=0;
    $start=false;
    for($i=$occurrence,$length=strlen($vContent);$i<$length;$i++){
        if($r===$l&&$l!==0&&($l+$r)%2===0) break;
        if($vContent[$i]==='('){
            if(!$start)
                $start=true;
            $r++;
        }

        if($vContent[$i]===')'&&$start){
            $l++;
        }
        if($start)
            $signature .=$vContent[$i];
    }
    //get only parameters as array
    preg_match_all("#\\$(\w+)#",$signature,$parameters);
    $counter++;
    //loop through the values to return the first false ,null or empty occurrence
     foreach($parameters[1] as $k=>$v){
        if(!func_get_arg($k)) return $v;
    }
    return false;//return false if every variables cast to boolean are true
}
```

with this you could easily do:

```
$data=7;
$data2=false;
$data3='';
$data4=null;
if(($false=checkfalseVar2($data,$data2,$data3))
    &&$true=
checkfalseVar2(/**/$data4/**/,$data2,$data3)){
      print($false);// output data2 
      print($true);// output data4
}
```

note that now the function return the name without the dollar sign `$` to allow direct use without eval in the code again using for example `$GLOBALS[$true]` or `$$true`

However I think **you must keep good practices by checking your variable manually because it is really less consuming**

```
if(!$data){...}elseif(...){}else{}
```

**beacause sometimes it is better to write more do gain more than write less and loose a lot**

**By writting a new function for this purpose you waste some times, maybe you slow your code a finally you can also consume more memory  like in my case so think about it too...**

Comment: I've added an edit to add some comments. It should be made clear to the OP that this will only work if both the function definition and the function call are within the same file, and that the arguments (the variables) are all provided in a single line.

Comment: Curious to know why you've chosen to go through the effort of parsing the source code to find the arguments. It's a relatively novel way of doing it. Just a small word of warning: the addition of the file read can be an expensive call. Working with variables in RAM is fast, but doing an I/O call to the disc is expensive; especially if the disc is busy seeking files for other scripts (or even if this script is run in parallel).

Comment: i know all this ...It is just to show that we can get the full list of variables in some cases without created manually an array.I'm aware of the inefficiency of this code...**So children don't do that at home....**

Comment: That's a very interesting piece of code you got here. However, as you point out, in the end it's more memory/performance efficient to do it manually. But I think your function still can be very useful. And no, I didn't find a solution. The solution is that there's no solution.  For a second I thought I could catch E_NOTICE information but that wouldn't be a bulletproof solution. As @RToyo stated there's no way of getting the information from PHP apart from going through every value.